# Alternative heavy right tailed distribution to exponential distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution

I have data whose distribution resembles an exponential distribution, but the data has a heavier tail than the exponential distribution.

I will be very glad for any recommendation of an alternative to the exponential distribution for the data.

Comment: A good basis for any such recommendation is a theory about the underlying process, because tail estimation can be highly uncertain without having a large amount of data.  What additional information can you supply about your problem?

Comment: @whuber , data is about the time duration(in months) between car accidents day and reporting day of accidents. But I dont have so much data. It seems that, most of the accidents are generally being reported quickly, but some of the accidents are being reported lately.  when, I fit the data with an exponantial distribution, I see that the tail seems so light compared with the data.

Comment: One might suppose there is a statute of limitations or insurance limit, most likely a whole number of years.  This wouldn't be modeled well by any standard heavy-tailed distribution.  You ought to closely examine what data you do have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your discussion with @whuber, I would suggest two approaches.

(1) A [mixture model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model), perhaps a mixture of exponentials for simplicity. One can think of these as a heirarchical model, where observations can come from different sub-populations and each sub-population has its own distribution. From what you've described, this sounds like the situation you are looking at; most people who get in an accident report it almost immediately to an insurance provider. Those who wait any significant amount of time are likely following very different patterns.

(2) [Kaplan-Meier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Meier_estimator). This is a non-parameteric approach that makes no assumptions about the baseline distributions. This is a very simplified approach that tells you what the data says, not what a constrained model of the data says.

Whether you want to use (1) or (2) depends on your use case; are you interested in knowing the proportion of subjects who don't follow the trend of reporting very quickly? Then (1) answers this question a little more directly (assuming a good fit). Are you just interested in seeing the overall distribution of time to reporting without a model's interpretation of the data? Then use (2).

Also, my advice is that even if you decide to use (1), you should still compare the overall fit with (2) as a form of model checking.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. My aim is making some simulations about the duration. I want to generate random data, for the different parameters of the underlying distribution. I guess, (1) seems more adequate for my aim. But,fitting such a distribution(s) may be hard. I will try for it.